# Sound disappeared after OSS installation

Tags: alsa, oss

I've installed the OSS backend from a deb64 package. And the sound in ubuntu is disappeared... Seems the audio card (hda nvidia) is not recognized anymore... What can I do?

*EDIT*

Sound now works, but OSS still don't... It seems to work not very well with ubuntu (also if it is shown in control panel).

Comment: sounds like a complaint veiled as a question, frowned upon per the faq.  It's possible to get it working, but sound has always been sketchy on linux.  OSS works with hda-intel on my laptop with very little tweaking.

Comment: Sometimes sound has problems (I've to restart the deamon) also with ALSA and Pulseaudio... The OSS never worked to me on hda-nvidia audio

Answer (score 2):

OSS is no longer supported by Ubuntu

> Canonical/Ubuntu has chosen to disable OSS support in their kernels
>   and ignore any bugs filed against OSS4 packages. If you're considering
>   using OSS4, you should probably use another Linux distro like Arch
>   Linux.

It also may be likely your hardware does not support OSS,  you can find the list of supported hardware [here](http://opensound.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/opensound/opensound/file/3db750724c2d/devlists/Linux)

If you really want to try to install and get OSS working you should have a read of the [Ubuntu Wiki Documentation for OpenSound](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound)